# Is there a way to download with python usging request, a csv that the url is like ‘Blob:https’

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, request, bots

I would like to download the state of industry CSV from OpenTable with a python bot,

but the URL of the CSV is of the form “`Blob: https`” and I could not use the request library.

What can I do to get the correct URL? or to download it using python and the blob URL? I can with Selenium, but I rather use the request library.

Answer (score 0):

To Get The Correct URL Try Making A proxy like mitmproxy https://mitmproxy.org
Or Some Software Like Burp Suit To Intercept The Traffic Between You as A Client And Website Server Then You Will Got The ALL HTTP Request With HTTP method And URL
And Body Data
May That Will Help You To Build Your BOT

[Intercepting HTTP Traffic with mitmproxy](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/intercepting-network-mitmproxy)

[Intercepting HTTP Traffic With BurpSuit](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/using)